# How can I put data from a struct into a dataGridView?

Tags: c#, struct, datagridview

I have a Windows Forms Application in C#.
I have a structure as follows:

```
public struct typeStruct
{
    public int field1;
    public long field2;
    public long field3;
    public long field4;
    public long field5;
    public long field6;
    public long field7;
    public int field8;
    public int field9;
    public string[] field10;
}
```

Then I do this:

```
public List<typeStruct> lstType = new List<typeStruct>();
public typeStruct t = new typeStruct();
```

Then I want to put t into a dataGridView on my form, but when I try the following the grid is not populated:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
```

I've been on Google and forums etc all day but am still no further forward. I'm quite a beginner, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That type should be a `class`, not a `struct`.

Comment: You have a variable called `t`?   I'm tempted to down-vote you.

Comment: @SteveWellens `t` as a variable name is fine. Field is not. (uncle bob says so). Here it is field, mistakenly you used the term variable.

Comment: field is just an example, the actual variables aren't called field.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel One letter variable names are not OK(I say so).

Comment: @SteveWellens It is fine if the scope of the variable is very short. For example what you name your for loop iteration variable? I prefer `i`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It is not appropriate on this site to have the discussion you want to have.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public List<typeStruct> lstType = new List<typeStruct>();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("field1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("field2", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("field3", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("field4", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("field5", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("field6", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("field7", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("field8", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("field9", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("field10", typeof(string));

            foreach (typeStruct ts in lstType)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(ts.all);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
    public class typeStruct
    {
        public int field1 { get; set; }
        public long field2 { get; set; }
        public long field3 { get; set; }
        public long field4 { get; set; }
        public long field5 { get; set; }
        public long field6 { get; set; }
        public long field7 { get; set; }
        public int field8 { get; set; }
        public int field9 { get; set; }
        public string[] field10 { get; set; }

        public object[] all
        {
            get { return new object[] { field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, string.Join(",", field10) }; }
            set {
                field1 = (int)value[0];
                field2 = (long)value[1];
                field3 = (long)value[2];
                field4 = (long)value[3];
                field5 = (long)value[4];
                field6 = (long)value[5];
                field7 = (long)value[6];
                field8 = (int)value[7];
                field9 = (int)value[8];
                field10 = ((string)(value[9])).Split(new char[] {','});
            }
        }

    }
}
```